# Delete entry from table and database in webmatrix/razor

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I have populated a table with info from my database, but I need another column where I can delete an entry out of the table and out of the database.

I've started to create a delete statement, but I don't know what I need to delete just a single entry.

Here's my code so far:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var sPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];
var roominfo = "SELECT * FROM RoomInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0";
var qroominfo = db.Query(roominfo, sPropertyId);
var droominfo = "DELETE ??? FROM RoomInfo"

if (IsPost){
    var deletesingleroom = db.Query(droominfo, sPropertyId);
}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
<h4>Room Information</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Room Title</th>
  <th>Room Type</th>
  <th>Room Description</th>
  <th>Delete Room</th>           
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var row in qroominfo)
{
<tr>
<td>@row.RoomTitle</td>
<td>@row.RoomType</td>
<td>@row.RoomDescription</td>
<td>
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Delete</button
</form>
</td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the delete statement in SQL in general, not particulary in Razor context.

The syntax for a delete statement is

```
DELETE FROM RoomInfo WHERE <some condition>
```

If you simply send this query :

```
DELETE FROM RoomInfo
```

This will delete all your rows.
So for deleting only one row from your POST result, it is kind of the same as the select :

```
DELETE FROM RoomInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0
```

Edit :

Now that you have a unique identifier that identifie the room you want to delete, you can update your code :

First, link the Id of your room to your delete button :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id-room" value="@row.RoomID">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Delete</button
</form>
```

And when you submit the delete form, retrieve the room Id to delete :

```
var sRoomId = Request.QueryString["id-room"];
var droominfo = "DELETE FROM RoomInfo WHERE RoomId = " + sRoomId
```

Note that this code is terrible and will have a lot of security holes.
You are not supposed to access the database in a razor file for example. You are working like if you were in old fashioned PHP.
Try to inform yourself about [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Comment: but the propertyID will be the same for all entries in the table, as it is there to show all rooms in that property. how would i delete just the one table row? but thanks, i've removed the generic query so that i dont delete everything by accident ;)

Comment: Show us your database schema, without it, it's hard to answer

Comment: if you mean you want to see all the columns in that table, they are RoomType, RoomDescription, RoomTitle and PropertyID. I am using webmatrix for this application

Comment: You pass in a value to the WHERE clause that uniquely identifies the row to delete. From the information you provided, you don't seem to have that so you need to add a unique identifier to your table.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i have now dropped the table, and created a new one with a unique id (roomid). Following on from Scorpi0s advice, i can create a WHERE clause, but i'm not sure how to pull the RoomID from the foreach statement?

Comment: Thanks Scorpio. I will test your code now. just one thing, i was always under the impression that with Razor, it was fine to access the database from the same page as the code, that's why it's such a simple tool?

Comment: In fact you are using Webmatrix, a tool which I'm not familiar with. So perhaps it is common to include database access from Razor file in Webmatrix. So my advice could be false :)

Comment: :) no worries dude, you have been extremely helpful, much appreciated.